# Disable highlight-line when in visual mode (evil mode)

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I'm new with emacs and I'd like to know how can we disable the highlight line mode (global-hl-line-mode) when we are in the VISUAL mode of Evil Mode. I find it really confusing when we start selecting a block with the hl-line activated, even if their background colors are different.
Of course, I want the hl-line-mode activated again when we leave the VISUAL mode. Thanks.

EDIT:  I tried this one and I was finally able to disable hl-line when in VISUAL mode.

(add-hook 'evil-visual-state-entry-hook (lambda ()
     (setq-local global-hl-line-mode
           nil)))

But I could not enable it when I leave. I tried this but it didn't work:

(add-hook 'evil-visual-state-exit-hook (lambda ()
     (global-hl-line-mode 1)))

EDIT: nevermind, this actually works:
(add-hook 'evil-visual-state-entry-hook (lambda ()
     (setq-local global-hl-line-mode
           nil)))

(add-hook 'evil-visual-state-exit-hook (lambda ()
     (global-hl-line-mode nil)))

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to disable hl-line-mode in the current buffer, rather than disable it globally:

```
(add-hook 'evil-visual-state-entry-hook (lambda() (hl-line-mode -1)))
(add-hook 'evil-visual-state-exit-hook (lambda() (hl-line-mode +1)))
```

Note that this may be a problem if you're not using `global-hl-line-mode`. `hl-line-mode` would be enabled each time you exit visual mode, whether or not hl-line-mode was on in the first place. This is what I hacked together to prevent that:

```
(defvar-local was-hl-line-mode-on nil)
(defun hl-line-on-maybe ()  (if was-hl-line-mode-on (hl-line-mode +1)))
(defun hl-line-off-maybe () (if was-hl-line-mode-on (hl-line-mode -1)))
(add-hook 'hl-line-mode-hook 
  (lambda () (if hl-line-mode (setq was-hl-line-mode-on t)))))

(add-hook 'evil-visual-state-entry-hook 'hl-line-off-maybe)
(add-hook 'evil-visual-state-exit-hook 'hl-line-on-maybe)
```

This way `hl-line-mode` won't be tampered with unless it was explicitly activated in the buffer beforehand, say, with a `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)`.

**EDIT:** fixed the hl-line-mode hook in the second snippet.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik L. You're right. Actually I'm disabling hl-line mode when I open for example ansi-term, so I don't want to enabe hl-line after I leave visual mode (I didn't notice that). But the snippet above doesn't seem to work. When I enter visual mode, the hl-line is still there...

Comment: @WalidBer My bad! There was a mistake in the second snippet. The if statement in the hl-line hook incorrectly checked `was-hl-line-mode-on` instead of `hl-line-mode`. I've fixed it. It should work now.